# Parse MS Word document for XMLfragments - C#

Tags: xml

I have a MS Word document which is having XML nodes along with plain text.

Could you please suggest me a way to parse this document and get the collection of all XML fragments that it have using C#.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can save that file as XML and parse it.